# Java - Combining two arrays?

Tags: java

What I'm trying to do is ask the user for a list of items, and create two arrays - one for the itemName and one for the itemPrice.  My program right now deals only with the itemPrice and there's no indication of how I can combine two arrays in one to output a list of both arrays combined, like this:

Bread - 1.20

Milk - 2.00

Here is what I have so far, two arrays, but the name array really isn't included in anything.  Thanks!

```
public class TaxClass
{
private Input newList;
/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Tax
 * Enter the number of items
 */
public TaxClass(int anyAmount)
{
    newList = new Input(anyAmount);
}
/**
 * Mutator method to add items and their cost
 * Enter the sales tax percentage
 */
public void addItems(double anyTax){
    double salesTax = anyTax;
    newList.setArray(salesTax);
}
}

public class Input
{
private Scanner keybd;
private String[] costArray;
private String[] itemArray;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Scanner
 */
public Input(int anyAmountofItems)
{
    keybd = new Scanner(System.in);
    costArray = new String[anyAmountofItems];
    itemArray = new String[anyAmountofItems];
}
/**
 * Mutator method to set the item names and costs
 */
public void setArray(double anyValue){
    for(int index=0; index < itemArray.length; index++){ 
    System.out.println("Enter the item name: ");
    itemArray[index] = keybd.next();}
    for(int indexa=0; indexa < itemArray.length; indexa++){
    System.out.println(itemArray[indexa]);
    double totalTax=0.0;
    double total=0.0;
    for(int indexc=0; indexc < costArray.length; indexc++){
       System.out.println("Enter the item cost: ");
       double cost = Double.valueOf(keybd.next()).doubleValue();
       totalTax = totalTax + (cost * anyValue);
       total = total + cost;
    }
    System.out.println("Total tax: " + totalTax);
    System.out.println("Total cost pre-tax: " + total);
    System.out.println("Total cost including tax: " + (total+totalTax));
}
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you couldn't create an object, for instance, called `Item` that has two string data members that hold the name and price for a particular item and then create an array of `Item`s?

Comment: Replace `Double.valueOf(keybd.next()).doubleValue();` with `keybd.nextDouble();`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to think it the Java way. **Completely forget arrays**. Create a class (like `Item`) with two fields (call them `name` and `price`) and put every `Item` in a `LinkedList`. Or create a map, like someone else suggested, but that's less simple and it's more urgent for you to *drop arrays*.

That even allows you to add a third field afterwards without re-thinking your code. It's called object-oriented programming.

But also in C you would create a struct enclosing two elements in order not to get crazy. In Java this is even simpler because Java is an high-level object-oriented language, and there's no memory management for you to do. Just use the facilities the programming language provides. They are many and do work. :)

Comment: Yeah, Java's an object-oriented language.  If you're not using objects, go back to writing C or FORTRAN.

Comment: guys, this is homework, so the use of arrays is probably a must. The exercise may be flawed but it is what it is.

Comment: In that case, he should use an array, but _at least_ an array of Item objects. A couple of arrays matched by index nowadays, in Java, is unacceptable... Even in C I've never done it that way

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be begging for a Map, really. But if you can rely on associated items being placed into the two different arrays at the same *index*, then you can safely use that index to associate the two items. So if 'Bread' goes into itemName[5] and '1.20' goes into itemPrice[5], then the index '5' binds the two. Find the index of 'Bread' and you can use that index on the other array to get its price.

Just bear in mind that you'll need to take care that you *can* rely on associated items being placed into the same index on both arrays. If you can't, this will fail, very horribly. A better approach is Giacomo's answer - create a nice class that will neatly encapsulate all this data and allow it to be stored without all this lookup hassle.

Comment: Correct answer but it is horrible, indeed, and it is not the Java way. :)